# How to convert http to https for my jira tool

Tags: apache, https, jira

In my organization we are used jira for project management, we want to secure it from http to https, we were tried a lot. please give me the proper solution

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tried with [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/arch-apache) from let's encrypt?